# Can I set a element of my mongoose model to be strictly of some particular other models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My subsection model should strictly be a type of lecture or quiz model only.
I want something like this. Any idea how to implement it properly?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const subSectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  subSection:{
      type:ObjectId,
      enum:["Lecture","Quiz"]
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("SubSection", subSectionSchema);
```

Although I can always do this way...check which type it is and set that value.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const subSectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  lecture: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Lecture",
  },
  quiz: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Quiz",
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("SubSection", subSectionSchema);
```

But I am looking for something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I think what you're looking for are [dynamic references](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref). This feature allow us to have dynamic properties on our MongoDB collection.

You'll basically need two properties for it, one for the ObjectID, other for the reference. Whenever you need to populate the reference, it will automatically detects which entity/collection to use.

Here's a quick example from Mongoose docs:

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema({
  body: { type: String, required: true },
  on: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    // Instead of a hardcoded model name in `ref`, `refPath` means Mongoose
    // will look at the `onModel` property to find the right model.
    refPath: 'onModel'
  },
  onModel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['BlogPost', 'Product']
  }
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', new Schema({ name: String }));
const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', new Schema({ title: String }));
const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was searching for something like this.